# (SOLVED) Computing $\int^\infty_0 \frac{x \sin x}{1+x^2}dx$ using the calculus of residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

[I am done with the problem, no need for any more help.]

The main obstacle I am running into is I don't know what curve to use. I have tried several, and all of them end up including a section which diverges.

My technique begins with noticing that $\int^\infty_0 \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}dx$=$\Im \int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{ix}}{1+x^2}dx$, and then solving for this value using residue theory.

The best curve I have been able to come up with is the union of the following sets (call it $\gamma$). For any given R, define

$\gamma_1 = \{ z : |z| = R, \Im z, \Re z \geq 0\}$

$\gamma_2 = \{ z : |z-i| = R^{-1}, \Re z \leq 0\}$

$\gamma_3 = \{z : \Re z = 0, 0\leq \Im z \leq R, |z-i|>R^{-1} \}$

$\gamma_4 = [0,R]$

Although $\int_\gamma= 2e^{-1}$ and $\int_{\gamma_2}=0$ I have computed that $\int_{\gamma_1}$ diverges so I don't think this approach will work, but I can think of no other curve which would allow me to do this calculation. Maybe I computed it wrong? I parameterized the curve with $z=Re^{i\theta}$ but you can bound the integral from below by $\frac{\frac{\pi R}{2}\cdot R^2\cdot e^R}{|1-R^2|}$ which clearly goes to infinity as R goes to infinity. Not really sure how to finish this problem.

Comment: Try using $x\sin x=(-x)\sin(-x)$. Then your integral is half of the integral with the lower limit at $-\infty$

Comment: Without residues, it is quite simple.